# facebook php login FBRLH_state session variable value changed after coming back from facebook

Tags: php, session, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to implement facebook login with the php sdk into my web application, but it doesn't work. For some reason, it seems like the value of $_SESSION["FBRLH_state"] has been modified after user comes back from the facebook page for permission for the app to access user's info.

Here are the codes that I am using:

facebookloginbutton.php

```
<?php

session_start();    
require_once 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '*****',
  'app_secret' => '*****',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$helper=$fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions=['public_profile']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl=$helper->getLoginUrl('mydomain.com/snslogin/fb-callback', $permissions);

//output the FBRLH_state here (name this state1)
echo $_SESSION["FBRLH_state"];

?>
<a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($loginUrl); ?>">facebook login</a>
```

fb-callback.php (only top portion of it)

```
<?php

session_start();    
require_once 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

//output $_SESSION["FBRLH_state"] (name this state2)
var_dump($_SESSION);

//output the state variable in the URL (name this state3)
echo '<br>'.$_GET["state"].'<br>';
```

In the above code, I get the same value for state1 and state3, but state 2 is for some reason different. Because these values are different, the program doesn't continue with the rest of the code for fb-callback.php.

I have done php login with facebook account in another web application, so I thought I knew what I was doing, but I just cannot find the mistake I am making.

Answer (score 0):

I think the settings do not allow cross site session sharing or something.

Comment: So you are saying "impossible". That is a somewhat short answer.

Comment: No i fixed it by saving the full Access token object variable that comes from the callback, in session and then use that session troughout the project

Comment: Would you like to increase your chances for positive feedback on this, by [edit]ing it according to [answer]?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
{
    $fbConfig = config('Facebook');
    
    $fb = new FacebookLogin([
        'app_id' => $fbConfig->appID,
        'app_secret' => $fbConfig->appSecret,
    ]);
    
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    
    $permissions = ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends'];

    if(!$this->session->has('fb_access_token'))
    {               
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
        
        if($accessToken)
        {               
            $this->session->set('fb_access_token', $accessToken);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $accessToken = $this->session->get('fb_access_token');
    }
    
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(base_url(route_to('facebook/callback')), $permissions);
    
    return redirect()->to($loginUrl);
}

public function callback()
{
    $usersModel = new UsersModel();     
        
    $fbConfig = config('Facebook');
    
    $fb = new FacebookLogin([
        'app_id' => $fbConfig->appID,
        'app_secret' => $fbConfig->appSecret,
    ]);
    
    $getResponse = $this->request->getGet(NULL);
    
    if(isset($getResponse['state']))
    {
        $this->ViewData['Metas'] = $this->getMetas($this->metaSeo['success']);
    
        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        
        if(!$this->session->has('fb_access_token'))
        {               
            $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
            
            $this->session->set('fb_access_token', $accessToken);
        }
        else
        {
            $accessToken = $this->session->get('fb_access_token');
        }
        
        $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email,location', $accessToken);
        
        $user = $response->getGraphUser();
        
        if($user->getEmail())
        {
            $UserFound = $usersModel->where('email', $user->getEmail())->first();
        
            if($UserFound)
            {   
                $this->session->set('user', $UserFound->id_user);
                
                $UserFound->setLastLogin();
                
                $usersModel->save($UserFound);
                
                return redirect()->to('account');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // email is required to acceess account
        }
        
        $this->ViewData['LayoutView'] = 'Facebook/Success';
    }
    else
    {
        $this->ViewData['LayoutView'] = 'Facebook/Errors';
        
        if($getResponse['error_reason'] == 'user_denied')
        {
            
        }
    }
    return view('MasterPages/Master', $this->ViewData);
}
```